# Using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` to automate `tabular` and `tikzpicture` environments

Tags: expl3

After much trial and error I have finally succeeded in automating the generation of tables, as per the MWE below. By generating the content for the `\l_rn_tableContent_tl` variable in a `\cs_` function one is relieved of the drudgery of doing it all manually. I was very hopeful to apply the same principle to the generation of `tikzpicture` environment content, but even invoking `\usepackage{tikz}` produces compile ERROR `!Missing number treated as zero`. Why? (First query). Why should I use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` over `\DeclarDocumentEnvironment`, both seem to work fine in the MWE below - (second query).

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 10 Nov 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION: Automating tabular and tikz environments. Tabular works as intended, but even invoking \usepackage{tikz} produces compile ERROR "!Missing number, treated as zero."
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableFormat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableContent_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myTreeTable}{mO{|c|c|c|}O{\hline \textbf{col~1} & \textbf{col~2} & \textbf{col~3} \\\hline\hline}}
{
  \begin{tabular}{#2}
  #3
  #1
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\textit{italic} &  $\alpha$ & 3.14159\\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {yy &  $\zeta$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {1 &  2 & a  \\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {A &  Z & XX  \\\hline}
    \begin{myTreeTable}{\l_rn_tableContent_tl}
    \end{myTreeTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not clear to me what you are achieving with this. Could you clarify? May be an example of what you write currently that you want to avoid and what you would ideally write? Plus what exactly doesn't work with TikZ? It's nice to have a full compilable example, but in this case I think it would be helpful if you provided a non-compilable example so we understand what are you trying to get at.

Comment: The error is really not your fault.

Comment: I take my first comment back. It is your fault ;-). You are missing the end environment argument and so your definition "eats" the `\ExplSyntaxOff` and then at `\begin{document}` a file is read with catcode space ignored and everything explodes. (This also explains why you can use expl3 commands in your document).

Comment: what is the intended syntax here? You are defining an enviornment but do not appear to be using anything inside the enviornment body between begin and end? why not define a command and use `\myTreeTable{\l_rn_tableContent_tl}` which would be a more natural syntax

Comment: @Manuel @David Carlisle Ulrike Fischer has provided me with an effective fix to my immediate problem and I have just been able to confirm that what I am doing with `tabular` also works for the `tikzpicture` environment. My syntax may well be screwed up, it often is. I am taking your comments on board and will take the time to  experiment.

Comment: @David Carlisle Quite right,  `\NewDocumentEnvironment` not required at all! Some weeks ago when proceeding in the fashion you are suggesting compiler errors resulted, I evidently drew the wrong conclusions and have been looking for alternatives ever since. I kept no records and will never find out where exactly I had gone wrong, thank goodness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your environment definition is missing an argument for the commands at the end of the environment and so it "eats" the \ExplSyntaxOff. This means that the expl3-Syntax is still active at `\begin{document}` and a file loaded there by tikz doesn't like this. This here works without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 10 Nov 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION: Automating tabular and tikz environments. Tabular works as intended, but even invoking \usepackage{tikz} produces compile ERROR "!Missing number, treated as zero."
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableFormat_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableHeader_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_tableContent_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myTreeTable}{mO{|c|c|c|}O{\hline \textbf{col~1} & \textbf{col~2} & \textbf{col~3} \\\hline\hline}}
{
  \begin{tabular}{#2}
  #3
  #1
  \end{tabular}
}{} %<--- missing
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {\textit{italic} &  $\alpha$ & 3.14159\\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {yy &  $\zeta$ & 3.14159  \\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {1 &  2 & a  \\\hline}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_rn_tableContent_tl {A &  Z & XX  \\\hline}

    \begin{myTreeTable}{\l_rn_tableContent_tl}
    \end{myTreeTable}
\ExplSyntaxOff    
\end{document}
```